# Error ITMS-90211: Invalid code signing entitlements

Tags: application-loader, gamesalad

I am trying to get my app through application loader and I am getting this error:

[image]

I have tried to remove the "*" but I cannot find a way to do so if someone could help me please.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is a little light on detail...  For us to help you we need to actually see the code that's causing the error, otherwise we can't help you debug it. Please *edit your question* and add in any relevant code snippets - also tell us anything that you have tried to fix it yourself (so we don't duplicate your previous efforts). Definitely put that in your question (not here in the comments) because code-formatting in comments is awful :P

Comment: This question does not appear to be about *programming*, because it's about the app store approval process. And FYI, I think I know the problem: Remove the `*` in `YK522L3Z86.*`. Did you bother to read the error?

Comment: Yes I did thank you for your help I diddnt really understand what it was saying and i dont think I can change it but i will try my best

Comment: @Laurel i checked and i cant find a way to remove the "*" thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Hiya - it's still in an image instead of in your question :)
If we wanted to eg copy/paste a section of error to google it... we couldn't do that. Also my guess would be to google for "updating my ubiquity-container-identifiers" and see where that gets you...